# Why triggering job B from job A in jenkins does not re-checkout, and how to force it to?

Tags: git, jenkins, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a jenkins' job jenkinsfile that looks like this:

```
stages {
     stage("X") {
         steps { build job: "Y", parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'build_number', value: "${BUILD_NUMBER}"]] }
     }
}
```

I see that job Y is triggered, but I got a jenkins error there

```
 "org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.lang.String BLA
"
```

I know this error from previous builds, so I checked out the commit that job Y run (the one triggered by stage X in my main job), and indeed, the commit it checked out was an outdated one. If I would have triggered job Y manually (i.e. "build with parameters") I would get a good run, without that error

1. Why triggering a job from another job does not include a checkout update?
2. How can I force an update to the commit the job is checking out
3. Are there any more differences between manual triggering and the I do?

---

This is my pipeline configure: [image: job]

Comment: So what does job `y` do?

Comment: please post some short of code for your  Y job.

Comment: I'm not near my computer right now but basically it is a small job. 3 stages. Install. scp. Small python script that calls pytest over the scp-ed file. The thing is I can verify Y works OK independently because it runs the correct commit, but when it is called via X the commit is old